# Ignore parts of sass file for parsing

Tags: css, sass, liquid

I'm trying to get SASS to ignore part of my .scss code while parsing.

It's for a shopify theme that I'm making. My scss files are compiled into .css.liquid files so that I can put shopify's templating language liquid into the css too.

I want the compiled css.liquid to look like this:

```
.header--logo {
  background: url({{ 'header-logo.png' | asset_url }}) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

In LESS I used to do this:

```
.header--logo {
  background: ~"{{ 'header-logo.png' | asset_url }}" 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Does SASS also have an easy way to do the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sass doesn't provide an escape-all-the-declaration feature.

To pass a CSS value as-is, without being parsed with Sass, put it into quotes and use the `unquote()` function to remove the quotes:

```
.header--logo {
  background: unquote("url({{ 'header-logo.png' | asset_url }}) 0 0 no-repeat");
}
```

If you use that very often, you can make it a tad easier with a helper function:

```
@function i($str) {
  @return unquote($str);
}

.header--logo {
  background: i("url({{ 'header-logo.png' | asset_url }}) 0 0 no-repeat");
}
```

Alternatively, you can "igonre" a part of the value rather than the whole value. You'll need interpolation to do this, i. e. `#{unquote('...')}`. Example usage:

```
.header--logo {
  background: url(#{unquote("{{ 'header-logo.png' | asset_url }}")}) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Demo of all approaches: http://sassmeister.com/gist/4920a805f0451192ec9b

Comment: My statement about interpolation was wrong, sorry. Updated again.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. 
 
The helper function is really useful, for readability I called it ignore() instead of i()

Comment: `ignore` isn't much shorter to type than `unquote`. :P

Comment: Yeah you're right, I wanted to include it in my mixin file so I could use it across all my files, but I'll stick to unquote instead. :)